# Adding vertical lines in algorithm2e outside of blocks

Tags: latex, pseudocode

I am using the package algorithm2e and notice that it has a great feature where vertical lines can be connected within "blocks" of code (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144840/vertical-loop-block-lines-in-algorithmicx-with-noend-option for examples). I am trying to add similar vertical lines connecting code that are not necessarily in blocks of if/else/while etc. but just to keep track of indents.

Below is a reproducible example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vlined]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}

\DontPrintSemicolon
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{Example keyword}
\KwResult{Example result}

/* \textit{Create first function}\;
function 1 = function(input, output)\{\;
\Indp/* \textit{Create inner function}\;
function 2 = function(input, output)\{\;
\Indp/* \textit{Perform main task}\;
mainTask(function1, function2)\;
\Indm\})\;
\Indm\}\;

\caption{Psuedocode for interactive scatterplot matrix}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to add vertical lines at the indents. An example of my goal end product (where I superimposed lines in green) looks as below:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to achieve these type of lines in this minimal working example would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Off hand, I think your best choice is to post this question at TeX - LaTeX SE.

Comment: Thank you. I just posted there now.